# How to save a picture to a file?

Tags: android, file, camera, save

I'm trying to use a standard Intent that will take a picture, then allow approval or retake.  Then I want to save the picture into a file.

Here's the Intent I am using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );

startActivityForResult( intent, 22 );
```

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) says:

> The caller may pass an extra EXTRA_OUTPUT to control where this
>   image will be written. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a
>   small sized image is returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field. If
>   the EXTRA_OUTPUT is present, then the full-sized image will be
>   written to the Uri value of EXTRA_OUTPUT.

I don't pass extra output, I hope to get a Bitmap object in the extra field of the Intent passed into `onActivityResult()` (for this request).  So where/how do you extract it?  Intent has a `getExtras()`, but that returns a Bundle, and Bundle wants a key string to give you something back.

What do you invoke on the Intent to extract the bitmap?

Comment: lol that sounds so obfuscated, why would you ever make an "intent" object, good ol' java and its weird ass classiness. To me java seems to take OO to the level where I begin to doubt its usefulness.

Comment: It isn't Java, gmatt.  It's android (Google phone API).   Intent objects are requests to system components to do some work for you.  Yeah, I agree it sounds obfuscated, but most of it makes sense when you learn the API.

Comment: hmm interesting, I'm sure it makes sense once you learn it--from an impartial observer's perspective it just looks unnecessarily obtuse, and my stab at Java probably stems from a couple years ago when I was forced to work with some callously over-complicated Java API's for my job. I guess you could say I'm bitter over the experience, but perhaps I shouldn't place Android in the same boat--after all, it may actually "work" through all those layers of abstraction, which is more to say than those API's I worked with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling `getExtras().get("data")` and casting the result to a `Bitmap`.

[See here for an example](http://my-hoa-ex.blogspot.com/2010/01/taking-photo-via-camera-is-actually.html).

Comment: Thank you - your answer, and your sample code work perfectly.

May I ask what steps you went through to put those pieces together?  Were you lucky enough to find some good material, or were you in a class, or are you one of the implementers, etc?

Comment: "May I ask what steps you went through to put those pieces together?" I searched on Google to find that blog post. While I have written three books on Android development, I have not used the camera `Intent` for thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

On a related note, if you have the "crop" activity come up after taking the picture using `intent.putExtra("crop", "true")`, you'll get the cropped URI from `getExtras().get("action")`.

I realize you've got this all fixed by now, just want to make sure no one tries to use this with crop and gets confused.

Reference: the apps-for-android [LolCat](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/LolcatBuilder/src/com/android/lolcat/LolcatActivity.java) activity.