# Is it possible to take a picture from a smart phone in the browser and save to database?

Tags: blackberry, cross-browser, iphone

I have an application that saves a user's webcam image using a pc/mac browser.

Is there a way to do the same thing using smart phone cameras within the browser?

I'm not really sure where I would begin.  A google search didn't give me many leads.

All the best,

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this on the iPhone using  [UIImageJPEGRepresentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageJPEGRepresentation).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451442/how-to-save-a-picture-to-a-file) questions describes how to do the same thing on Android.

These are examples for two platforms.  Are there any other platforms you are looking to develop your application for?

Comment: Symbian perhaps - the assertion that "those are to two most common platforms" is a little flawed (see the Wikipedia article for Smartphone for a graph of relative market share). iPhone OS is only the third most common smartphone platform, and Android a distant fifth!

Comment: Although, they are probably the two largest platforms as far as app downloads.  This article suggests that "Apple responsible for 99.4% of mobile app sales in 2009": http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2010/01/apple-responsible-for-994-of-mobile-app-sales-in-2009.ars